# Finding nth largest element inplace

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, nth-element

I need to find nth largest element in an array and currently I'm doing it the following way:

```
std::vector<double> buffer(sequence); // sequence is const std::vector<double>
std::nth_element(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin() + idx, buffer.end(), std::greater<double>());
nth_element = buffer[idx];
```

But is there any way to find the n-th largest element in an array without using an external buffer?

Comment: What is the type of `sequence`, and what is `SignalType`? Why can't you use `sequence` directly?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You can use `nth_element` on any sequence that is accessible with Random Access iterators. But the sequence will be modified (partially sorted) in the process. Do you mean you want an `nth_element` that does not modify the sequence it is working on?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is some other approach to find the nth largest element in an array? Because the sequence can be big and I don't want to spend time on copying it but also it should stay unchanged.

Comment: Is array sorted or unsorted?

Comment: @haccks, no sequence is unsorted

Comment: @aob. I'm not sure what you want. State in words what you want e.g. I want to find the position of the first element that is greater than

Comment: He wants an `nth_element()` function that doesn't modify the container.

Comment: @MichaelBurr. The question is really whether nth_element is the correct algorithm for his requirement...

Comment: Is there repetition? If not you could use a set.

Comment: It's probably not possible to do this with o(min{k, n-k}) (little-oh) space where n is the number of elements and you want to find the k-th largest element.

Comment: Hm nevermind, I stand corrected: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397595002251 However, these are not linear time it seems. And probably entirely impractical

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid copying the entire buffer without modifying the original range by using [`std::partial_sort_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy). Simply copy the partially sorted range into a smaller buffer of size `n`, and take the last element.

If you may modify the original buffer, then you can simply use `std::nth_element` in place.

Comment: Note that complexity would be `O(n log n)` versus `O(n)` for the copy + `std::nth_element`.

Comment: @Jarod42 `O(s log(min(s, n)))` to be exact, where `s` is size of buffer and `n` is from "n-th". Indeed, this might only be worthwhile if the difference of `s` and `n` is great enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the partition function used in Quick Sort to find the nth largest elements.

The partition function will divide the original array into two parts.The first part will be smaller than A[i], The second part will be larger than A[i],partition will return i.If i is equal to n, then return A[i].If i is smaller than n,then partition the second part.If i is larger than n,then partition the first part.

It won't cost you extra buffer,and the average time cost is O(n).

Comment: This only needs to find the nth largest element,not the same as Quick Sort.You can refer to "Introduction to Algorithm" 9.2.@JonathanMee

Comment: Note that the partition function takes a random element, *that element will not necessarily be the 9th*. Your own statement: "If *i* is smaller than *n*,then partition the second part. If *i* is larger than *n*,then partition the first part." Clearly indicates that we we must look at elements more than once to find the 9th so this is *not* *O(n)*.

Comment: @JonathanMee The algorithm described here is actually called [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect). Since you always know which "half" to descend into, you get expected linear time. Of course you might look at elements more than once, but only an amortized constant number of times per element (again, expected value here)

Comment: However this does not answer the question at all. Quickselect is probably exactly what `std::nth_element` implements, but it is in-place which OP wants to avoid

Comment: @NiklasB. "Of course *you might look at elements more than once*, but only an amortized constant number of times per element (again, expected value here)" Negative Ghost Rider, what you are describing is *O(n log(n))*, not *O(n)*.

Comment: You can read the 9.2 "Selection in expected linear time" part of "Introduction to Algorithm" .@JonathanMee

Comment: @JonathanMee Nah, the recurrence is T(n) < O(n) + T(a * n), with high probability for 0 < a < 1, which resolves to T(n) = O(n) according to the master theorem

Comment: QuickSelect (the algorithm you describe) is exactly what `nth_element` does and it *does* modify the sequence. So this is not an answer to OP.

Comment: What is OP?@IlyaPopov@Niklas B.